# Where are the results of the smoke mortar measurements of the shock wave in nuclear tests?

Tags: shock-waves

Smoke mortars were used in nuclear tests to measure the passage of the shock wave.
The passage of the shock wave could be detected by the sunlight reflected from the smoke trails being refracted through the shock wave, and high speed cameras were used to record this passage, enabling the scientists to accurately measure the passage of the shockwaves through the smoke.

This is widely reported in publicly available reports.
Unfortunately the reports I have retrieved only describe the process, but not the results.

I would be grateful if anyone could let me know where I could find some of the results?

[EDIT]
I have found an [analysis of the TEAPOT](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/trecms/pdf/AD0611253.pdf) test data  which looked promising. However for Shot 12, p. 75 it states "The velocities obtained from Equation 3.4 are reported in Table 3.20 and plotted in Fig. 3.38 as a function of distance. "

Equation 3.4 comes from  an obscure[Moulton-Hanlon paper](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/citations/AD0363573%20is) which in which the derivation is illegible!

So I'm still looking for some experimental results, as oppposed to formula-generated graphs like 3.38 (above).

Comment: Well, Livermore has digitized many of the films. See https://str.llnl.gov/october-2017/spriggs

Comment: I would assume that a lot of the details of American tests are still classified and probably will stay that way for a long time. Since we have some of the footage, it shouldn't be too hard to extract at least some physical data from it. The difficulty may lie in correlating it to the actual performance of the device, since that may still be a guarded secret.

Comment: https://www.energy.gov/management/articles/fehner-and-gosling-atmospheric-nuclear-weapons-testing-1951-1963-battlefield May point to some resources. My experience with reporting from that era is it is all considered classified and would need a derivative declassifier to release.

Comment: See my [EDIT] above.